# Can i apply filter: inver(1) with transform-origin in CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to animate image by filter: invert(1) going from right side to the left side.

```
filter: invert(1);
transform-origin: right;
```

Seems to not be working. Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you aren't changing the image with a transform, you're changing it with a filter. The `transform-origin` property will not affect a filter in any way, only transforms. If I were you I would try something like my example below. Hover the image to see the effect.

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container:before {
  content: '';
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: 1s ease;
}

.image-container:hover:before {
 transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/400/300" alt="" />
</div>
```